# My custom usb is recognized as physical keyboard when attached to Sony mobiles

Tags: keyboard, usb, sony, sony-xperia

I am developing a product base Android app. That product is behaving absolutely fine in normal Android devices. But behaving bit weird with Sony Xperia mobiles. It is getting recognized as physical keyboard over there. Somehow I successfully detected it when my app is launched manually.

But, the actual requirement is to launch my app as the product is attached to mobile.

Can anyone tell me, why my product is recognized as keyboard instead of normal usb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sony Company itself say, they do not guarantee that all usb devices would be supported on Sony devices.
Ref: http://support.sonymobile.com/global-en/xperiaz4tablet/userguide/Connecting-your-device-to-USB-peripherals/
https://support.sonymobile.com/gb/xperiaz3compact/userguide/Connecting-your-device-to-USB-peripherals/

There might be some issue in the code written for your USB device detection. Which might be leading to treat device as physical keyboard by-default.
Ref: [Uinput virtual device is detected as physical keyboard on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979532/uinput-virtual-device-is-detected-as-physical-keyboard-on-android)